# array values and print specified number of characters

Tags: powershell

I have a variable which contains a list of contents as an array.

```
$procs = @{name="explorer",type="svchost"}
```

How do I access the value of first element (i.e. `explorer`) from the array and store into a variable?
And then print the first three letters of that value (i.e. `exp`)?

Comment: That's not an array but a hash (comma should be semi-colon). You can access the information you want through this: $procs.name.Substring(0, 3)

Comment: thanks David, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
 # for the first tree letters of the first hash table value
 $NewVar = (@($procs.Values)[0]).Substring(0,3)

 # for the first tree letters of a specific hash table element (name)
 $NewVar = ($procs.name).Substring(0,3)
```